# How to store many optional fields in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord

I'm working on an app that displays **Products**. Each Product is a model (Product) with some common info like name, brand etc. To separate what kind of Product we're looking at we have a **product_type** (like: Phone, TV, Sofa etc) which is basically a tinyint field (e.g. 1 = Phone, 2 = TV).

Now, **depending on the product_type each Product can have different options**: if it's a phone the Product should have extra info associated (like weight, does it have LTE, does it have a front-facing camera etc), a TV should have info like display size and so on.

**My question is: What is the *best /or/ easiest* way to add this extra data to the Product, depending on the type of Product?**

I was thinking of having an extra model **ProductOptions** with fields product_id, option_type, option_value (VARCHAR) which would store extra fields, but I'm not sure if this is optional for performance & search. In this case, searching would mean finding all ProductOptions that match a given criteria (e.g. `po = ProductOption.where(:option_type => "LTE", :option_value => "yes")` ) and then doing a `Product.findAllIn(po)` to find the actual products.

Or should I go with Postgres and use HStore? Is HStore efficient when searching?

Any ideas?

*Rails newbie, all code is pseudo-code*

Answer (score 2):

If you're already looking at ProductType, you might make this [Single-Table Inheritance](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html) and actually define different product types. That would be easier to code anyway. In this case:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # common functionality goes here
end

class Sofa < Product
  # sofa specific functionality goes here
end
```

You can then put all the options on the product table, but have a different attr_accessible, validations, and views for the different product types.

The best part about this setup is it 'just works' in rails, all you have to do is put a `type` column on the products table. Also, it lets you find all sofas like so:

```
Sofa.all
```

and all everything like so

```
Product.all
```

As far as database performance, well, you'll end up with a fair number of null fields, but all your attributes will be searchable (unlike serialization), and you only need to query on one table. So, I would expect this to outperform any other option I know of.

Plus, it's nice and object oriented. :)

Good luck, welcome to Rails!